# If i put UIView B on UIView A and hide/show them by using Segmented Control is it Professional way?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to handle UIViews hide/show by using (isHidden) UISegmented Control is it professional way how can i handle this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var flightTypeSegCont: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func flightType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    if(flightTypeSegCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        self.direcrCard.isHidden = false
        self.ViaCardView.isHidden = true
    }
    else
    {
        self.direcrCard.isHidden = true
        self.ViaCardView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: It all depends upon your use case. I don't see any issue in the solution if it is getting you what you want.

Comment: its not working it shows only both Views when we Run this App but when we select View B , than B got hide and never show again

Comment: Initially hide both the views when the controller is loaded first.

Comment: what is `direcrCard` & `ViaCardView` views. If those are tables you can use a single view and change data on it. If they are just random UI components and cannot use shared view it's fine. Anyway, you have to set initial values on `viewDIdLoad` method. Then this code will work fine. unless some other place making a mess.

Comment: @RJE how can i handle all components on one Page because i want to show about 10 labels on 1st Index other different 10 by clicking 1 index on segmented Control

Comment: you can just rename labels, but if it labels what you are doing it fine, but think if there is any other way to do that, maybe a table with 10 rows for your 10 labels, or some kinda `tag cloud` kinda view, anyway if you wanna do this way it's fine, and it should work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var flightTypeSegCont: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func flightType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let shouldHide = flightTypeSegCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    self.direcrCard.isHidden = !shouldHide
    self.ViaCardView.isHidden = shouldHide
}
```